# Python: getting \\u00bd correctly in editor

Tags: python, vim

I would like to do the following:
1) Serialize my class
2) Also manually edit the serialization dump file to remove certain objects of my class which I find unnecessary.

I am currently using python with simplejson. As you know, simplejson converts all characters to unicde. As a result, when I dump a particular object with simplejson, the unicode characters becomes something like that "\u00bd" for 好.

I am interested to manually edit the simplejson file for convenience. Anyone here know a work around for me to do this?

My requirements for this serialization format:
1) Easy to use (just dump and load - done)
2) Allows me to edit them manually without much hassle. 
3) Able to display chinese character

I use vim. Does anyone know a way to conver "\u00bd" to 好 in vim?

Comment: Isn't \u00bd the "one half" symbol?

Comment: actually something like that \\u597d

I pasted the wrong thing sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `json`/`simplejson` to produce unicode output instead of str output with Unicode escapes then you need to pass `ensure_ascii=False` to `dump()`/`dumps()`, then either encode before saving or use a file-like from `codecs`.

Comment: that did it. I never thought the answer is so simple

THX!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about simplejson or the Serialisation part of the question, but you asked about converting "\u00bd" to 好 in Vim.  Here are some vim tips for working with unicode:

- You'll need the correct encoding set up in vim, see:

  ```
  :help 'encoding'
  :help 'fileencoding'
  ```
- Entering unicode characters by number is simply a case of going into insert mode, pressing Ctrl-V and then typing `u` followed by the four digit number (or `U` followed by an 8-digit number).  See:

  ```
  :help i_CTRL-V_digit
  ```
- Also bear in mind that in order for the character to display correctly in Vim, you'll need a fixed-width font containing that character.  It appears as a wide space in [Envy Code R](http://damieng.com/blog/2008/05/26/envy-code-r-preview-7-coding-font-released) and as various boxes in Lucida Console, Consolas and Courier New.
- To replace `\uXXXX` with unicode character `XXXX` (where X is any hexadecimal digit), type this when in normal mode (where `<ENTER>` means press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, don't type it literally):

  ```
  :%s/\\u\x\{4\}/\=eval('"' . submatch(0) . '"')/g<ENTER>
  ```

Note however that u00bd appears to be unicode character ½ (1/2 in case that character doesn't display correctly on your screen), not the 好 character you mentioned (which is u597D I think).  See [this unicode table](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html).  Start vim and type these characters (where `<Ctrl-V>` is produced by holding `CTRL`, pressing `V`, releasing `V` and then releasing `CTRL`):

```
    i<Ctrl-V>u00bd
```

You should see a small character looking like 1/2, assuming your font supports that character.

Comment: Sweet.  Thanks for this.  I hadn't seen this.  Also ^vx followed by 2 digits works.